# Uniform continuity of sums and quotients

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R} $ and $f,g : A \to \mathbb{R} $ uniformly continuous and $g(x) \neq 0 $  then show that $f(x) + g(x) $ is uniformly continuous bur $\frac{ f(x) }{g(x) } $ may not be uniformly continuous

#### Attempt:

Let $\epsilon > 0 $. We can find $\delta_1, \delta_2 > 0 $ such that if for any $x,y \in A $ with $|x-y| < \delta_i $ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon / 2 $ and $|g(x) - g(y) | < \epsilon / 2 $. Take $\delta = \min ( \delta_1, \delta_2 ) $, then for any $x,y \in A $ with $|x-y| < \delta \leq \delta_i $ we must have that $| (f(x) + g(x)) - (f(y) + g(y)) | = | f(x) - f(y) + g(x) - g(y) | \leq |f(x) - f(y) | + | g(x) - g(y) | < \epsilon $. so $f + g$ is uniformly continuous on $A$.

as for the quotient, I feel as if I we need boundedness of $g$ is we want $f/g$ to be uniformly continuous. How can I find a counter example to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=1$ is uniformly continuous on $]0,+\infty[$,

$g(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous on $]0,+\infty[$,

but $f/g=1/x$ is *not* uniformly continuous on $]0,+\infty[$.

Answer (score 3):

Try using simple functions. For example, $\frac 1x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, even though it is a quotient of two uniformly continuous functions.

Comment: thanks a lot! is my first part of my question correct ? I mean my proof to fist part is correct?